# How to add a Table in a database that in working on host with EF code first?

Tags: database, entity-framework, ef-code-first, code-first

I have site and in is working and this site's database have many records , i want to add table in this database using EF code first, at the same time, i don't want to lose any data in my site.

Excuse me for my bad English language ;)

Comment: Is there a specific problem you're having with this?  This is very vague and it is unlikely anyone will be able to guess what problem you're having.

Comment: i want to add tabale in my database with ef code first but i don't want to use wizard in vs because my database uploaded in host

Comment: possible duplicate of [Code First Migrations With Existing Table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12088346/code-first-migrations-with-existing-table) or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17736708/unable-to-run-ef5-migration-with-existing-database

Comment: Have you enabled migrations or have you enabled automatic migrations?

Comment: i want to enabale migrations but it isnt run in package manager console !!! return this eror = Enable-Migrations : The term 'Enable-Migrations' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable 
program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ Enable-Migrations
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Enable-Migrations:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

Comment: possible duplicate of [Package Manager Console Enable-Migrations CommandNotFoundException only in a specific VS project](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10411529/package-manager-console-enable-migrations-commandnotfoundexception-only-in-a-spe)