# Using entity to connect to existing table

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, datacontext

I have a solution that I have been creating for a while and I have used EF Code First migrations to create the database. Recently for another solution my supervisor ran some scripts on the database that added a few tables.  Now, I need to connect to those tables in my solution.  I have this code here:

```
public class RoleMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Role>
{
    public RoleMap()
    {
        //Primary key
        this.HasKey(t => t.RoleId);

        this.Property(t => t.ApplicationId)
            .IsRequired();

        this.Property(t => t.Description)
            .HasMaxLength(256);

        this.Property(t => t.RoleName)
            .IsRequired()
            .HasMaxLength(256);

        this.Property(t => t.LoweredRoleName)
            .IsRequired()
            .HasMaxLength(256);


        this.ToTable("aspnet_Roles");
        this.Property(t => t.RoleId).HasColumnName("RoleId");

        this.Property(t => t.ApplicationId).HasColumnName("ApplicationId");
        this.Property(t => t.Description).HasColumnName("Description");
        this.Property(t => t.LoweredRoleName).HasColumnName("LoweredRoleName");
        this.Property(t => t.RoleName).HasColumnName("RoleName");

    }
}

static DataContext()
{
       Database.SetInitializer<DataContext>(null);
}

public DataContext(): base("DefaultConnection")
{
}


public DbSet<Role> Roles { get; set; }

protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
     modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new RoleMap());

}
```

I found this code in this link:

http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/661053/Entity-Framework-Code-First-Map

Unfortunately, when I try to create a new migration - it is trying to create a new table (even though I told it the table already exists).

```
public partial class addRoles : DbMigration
    {
        public override void Up()
        {
            CreateTable(
                 "dbo.aspnet_Roles",
                 c => new
                    {
                        RoleId = c.Guid(nullable: false),
                        ApplicationId = c.Guid(nullable: false),
                        Description = c.String(maxLength: 256),
                        LoweredRoleName = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 256),
                        RoleName = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 256),
                    })
                .PrimaryKey(t => t.RoleId);

       }

       public override void Down()
       {
            DropTable("dbo.aspnet_Roles");
       }
  }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12088346/code-first-migrations-with-existing-table

Answer (score 0):

With the help of JamieD77 I found the solution.  It is a combination of the code first mapping found in this link:

[Code First Mapping](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/661053/Entity-Framework-Code-First-Map)

and then here, add -ignorechanges when add-migration

[Code First Migrations With Existing Table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12088346/code-first-migrations-with-existing-table)